# What determines character encoding in C++

Tags: c#, c++, windows, encoding

I'm developing for Windows, the software is a client-server solution, the client is written in C# and the server is written in C++.

Today I wanted to develop a simple function: sending a string from the client side, receive it on the server side, and write it to an xml file.

My problem is that the characters I see on the server side are ANSI encoded. According by my knowledge, C# string is encoded by unicode, why does my server side c++ app encode the string as ANSI? I think my communication module doesn't modify the string.

Comment: do the strings in the server come from hard coded strings in code, a file or user input?

Comment: pure c++ and unicode don't go well togheter......

Comment: I cant help you with the C++ part but strings in C# are actually UTF-16 encoded. (What is kinda like utf-8, but worth the note.)

Comment: @Exceptyon this is not true.

Answer (score 2):

Well, C# strings are UTF16 encoded. 
you might want to use `std::u16string` instead of the regular `std::string`

other option is to encode the C# string into/from different encoding like UTF8 with the  `System.Text.Encoding` class.

Since IO actions are much more slow than CPU actions, and since IO action time is also porportional to the memory size involved, and UTF8 is usually leaner than UTF16, the common practice is to communicate through the web with UTF8.

hence, I'll go with converting the C# strings to UTF8 before actually sending them and use `std::string` in the server side.

Keep in mind though, that `std::string` is not that UTF8 aware, so writing something like `str[0]` might not give you the full UTF8 sequence, but only the first character of it.

Comment: Thanks for helping, actually I encode the string at C# client into UTF8 and found the  string get from C++ server still ANSI. Is windows did this for me? Is there any way I can just keep the encode type whether they're from.

Comment: do you mean that the strings you send from the client appear as ASCII in the messages the server gets?

Comment: Yes, that makes me very upset, I'm wondering if the OS did it. Maybe changed by locale? The workstation is not in English region.

Comment: can you give an example to a string that you send from the client?

Comment: It contains some Chinese letter, like: ”add|哥斯拉“    "add" means I want to add some words to the xml file, "|" is the separator, "哥斯拉“ is the string I want to write into the xml.   In fact the xml tool I use support only UTF8 string, so I have to encode the ANSI string to UTF8 before using it.

Comment: ok, and what is the string you see in the server? can you present is an array of integer values?

Comment: Never works on C#, but string is a higher level concept, when writing to socket, string is converted to byte array, this is what happens in qt. You need to generate the byte array with multi byte encoding, then in the server side, convert to string with multi-byte encoding.